# What is default timeout in setTimeout() method of JavaScript Window object?

Tags: javascript

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) timeout is required parameter. But it is possible to call it without timeout parameter.

```
function eventHandler(e) {
    var t = setTimeout(function () {
        clearTimeout(t);
        alert('Called');
    });
}
```

Comment: then what is the use of that

Comment: in PhantomJS the callback is called immediately

Comment: @PP. do you mean "after a very short period of time" or "synchronously"?

Comment: Refer [timeout w/od delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083594/call-settimeout-without-)delay

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The [HTML5 `Timer` spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#timer-initialization-steps) says:

> 5) Let timeout be the second method argument, or zero if the argument was omitted.

Comment: Lots of people are saying that this isn't useful, but I ran into a case where it fixed a problem with scrollIntoView() when using show/hide logic.

Answer (score 17):

Why don't you check it out for yourself?
Documentation is always welcome, however you can't beat real-world examples:

```
var startTime = Date.now();
setTimeout(function () {
    var endTime = Date.now();
    alert("timeOut was: " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/losnir/PbJBA/
Have a go by playing with different timeout values.

Not passing an a timeout arguments is practically the same as passing a `0`.
However, as you can see, the timeout is never `0`,  that is because your callback function will be placed in a queue, and executed as soon as possible (given your requested timeout value).

It goes to about 5ms on average, and if your UI thread is doing some intensive tasks, or your CPU is busy - it can go as **high as a couple hundreds of milliseconds, atrocious**!

Comment: 50 ms? That seems too high. Of course, your fiddle script is executed during the file is parsed and the whole jsFiddle environment is loaded so it can take longer, but usually it should be down to around 4ms.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. Should be 5ms, not 50ms.

Comment: try running again... the interval varies.....for me it went from `600ms` to `1ms`.

Comment: @Arun Exactly what I said 5 years ago. It happens since the JSFiddle environment is loaded at first.

Comment: @losnir have you ever heard about async? setTimeout does not assure that it will run after specified time it only confirms that function inside will be ran not sooner than specified time.

Comment: @Aivus No need to be condescending. Asynchronous operation is the heart of `setTimeout`, so yeah, of course I've "heard" about it. However it does not explain the rest of your comment -- the nature of guaranteeing the *minimum* timeout is thanks to how Timers are implemented in JavaScript and it a being single-threaded language. John Resig explains it well here: https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/
Finally, I never claimed otherwise (see `executed as soon as possible` in original answer), so your comment is pretty much moot. Have a nice day!

Comment: @losnir what I meant is that saying "It goes to about 5ms on average, and if your UI thread is doing some intensive tasks, or your CPU is busy - it can go as high as a couple hundreds of milliseconds, atrocious!" is just false information. For everyone it will be different based on environment and trying to predict it by running real world example is not the best idea.

Comment: @Aivus The author asked what is the default time-out, but there isn't one. I suggested doing a "real world example" so he can experiment for himself and understand that the timeout value is not guaranteed, nor it is synchronous.  That last sentence just shows a very big generalization on JSFiddle, and should not be used to "predict" anything. It could have been paraphrased though.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to set a timeout then just pass `0`

```
setTimeout(function() {
    ...
}, 0);
```

Alternatively you can just omit the delay parameter and `0` is assumed, however, for robustness (and general readability) it's best to pass *something* in there.

Note - this **does not** guarantee that your code will run *immediately*. It queues your task to run whenever the UI thread is available to process it.

Answer (score 4):

[According to the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html#get-the-timeout):

> When the above methods are to get the timeout, they must run the
>   following steps:
>
> - Let timeout be the second argument to the method, or **zero if the    argument was omitted**.
> - Apply the ToString() abstract operation to timeout, and let timeout be the result. [ECMA262]
> - Apply the ToNumber() abstract operation to timeout, and let timeout be the result. [ECMA262]
> - If timeout is an Infinity value, a Not-a-Number (NaN) value, or negative, let timeout be zero.
> - Round timeout down to the nearest integer, and let timeout be the result.
> - Return timeout.

Note that a specified timeout of zero may not actually delay for zero milliseconds. See [the specification of `setTimeout`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout) for further details.

Comment: +1 for citing the spec, but it seems to have changed since 2011. The [current draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout) requires it to be a `long` right away and does not use EcmaScript casting operations…

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the correction. The underlying point stands: If you want to know what the rules are, go read the rules.

Comment: Sure :-) However on the internet you also need to read some independent sites about whether the rules are followed by the targeted clients… :-P

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can all it without providing the time, but it will of no use

```
setTimeout(
function() {
 alert("asdf");
    })
```

it will fire on next tick

yes but it will make that function Asynchronous, or Queued for later

```
setTimeout(function() { alert("msg1");
    })
alert("msg2");
```

in above code msg2 is displayed first.

Comment: No, it does not fire immediately. It'll fire in the next tick.

Comment: OK i changed my answer.

Comment: No, it's not on a different thread. Your page is single threaded - by calling setTimeout you put your callback function in a queue to be dealt later.

Comment: This is not of no use: this will wait until all the previous tasks in the queue are executed