# How to show fullpage loader/spinner before React App finish loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web-applications

How to make fullpage loader/spinner that will load first and then will be shown until React (or different JS based framework) app fully loads.

With "fully load" I mean the moment when the browser's spinner stops spinning.

I was doing those loaders/spinners for non-js rendered websites, but I am not sure how to make them for JS-rendered apps.

How do I know when the root div is filled with fully loaded React app?

Answer (score 3):

You can put a loading sign in `index.html` inside a div that is given to any SPA (usually `root` or `app`). This will be override as soon as full application is loaded. For example, put a following style inside the `head` tag of `index.html`.

```html
<style>
    .loading {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2 );
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-top-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4 );
        animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
        -webkit-animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
        left: calc(50%);
        top: calc(50%);
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        }

        @keyframes spin {
        to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
        }
</style>
```

And put following inside the body tag.

```html
<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="loading"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem too and I managed to do it this way somehow:

in my `index.html`:

```html
<body
    <div id="spinner" class="container">
        <img src="src/assets/img/loader.svg" alt="loading...">
    </div>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

And in my `App.js`:

```js
function App() {
  
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  const spinner = document.getElementById("spinner")

  if (spinner){
    setTimeout(() => {
      spinner.style.display = "none";            
      setLoading(false)
    })
  }

  return (
        !loading && (
        <div className="App">

        // components to be loaded.

      </div>
        )
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Note**:
The setTimeout() with no time specified (or specify 0 doesn't matter as it's default is 0) is **necessary**, if you skip it, your app will get stuck in an infinite rendering loop.

For more info: [Call setTimeout without delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083594/call-settimeout-without-delay)

*

> also you can write it this way:

```
  // const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const loading = false
  const spinner = document.getElementById("spinner")
  if (spinner){
    setTimeout(() => {
      spinner.style.display = "none";            
      // setLoading(false)
    })
  }
```

- 