# Is there a React equivalent of Vue's nextTick() function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, dom

Vue has this [`nextTick`](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick) function, which is an async function that waits until the DOM is flushed. This is particularly useful when you want to perform some operation directly upon an element, like scrolling a DIV with [`scroll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll). This avoids the need to wrap this call into a blind [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).

In React I resorted to `setTimeout()` in the past. Is there an equivalent to `nextTick()`, or any better way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case it's possible to use `setTimeout` to achieve this goal.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#late_timeouts

Because it will execute function given in parameter in the end of the current thread, it's close to the behaviour of `Vue.nextTick`.

Example : https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-roman-y0b9un?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I was unaware of calling `setTimeout` without [specifying the delay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9083594/6923555). That's pretty much it.

Comment: Thats pretty cool actually, however i dont think its the best react approach :D but cool trick indeed

Comment: After several years of experience of facing this issue occasionally, mostly to do with focus/select/interact with dom elements upon state update/create conditionally on demand. `useEffect` is never the cleanest solution even the most wrong solution sometimes as it will run regardless all the complex situation. otherwise you have to do tons of complex dom element `ref` check, as React18 will run `useEffect` twice in strict dev mode, it brings extra development overhead to handle this problem.
This answer is the probably closest and yet the disappointed one we can get for React FC.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `reactHooks` to work with the lifecycle of your application.

In your **functional** component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'React'

useEffect(() => {
   // your method
}, []);
```

This will render in the first render.

You can set dependencies to be listened to when its changes.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'React'

useEffect(() => {
   // your method
}, [yourDependence]); //it will run every yourDependence change and the first time.
```

Answer (score 1):

In React class components, you can use the `componentDidMount` for the 1st render & `componentDidUpdate` for the subsequent renders, to perform DOM updates.

`componentDidMount`

> Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

`componentDidUpdate`

> Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

For functional components, there is the `useEffect` hook.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html